# C++ Storing Callback Functions Inside Struct Vector - Performance, Call Options, Deallocation Issues

Tags: c++, events, input, callback

I am currently experimenting in designing an InputHandler class, which will be responsible for storing callback functions, registered to its instance from various objects, and calling those functions when necessary actions and events occur. For this, I have a structure like this: (Edited and written the whole of the struct)

```
struct EventContainer {

public:
    EventContainer();
    EventContainer(EventType t, SDL_Scancode k, std::function<void()>&& cb, int pid) : Type(t), m_Key(k), Callback(cb), m_ID(pid) {}
    EventContainer(const EventHolder& c) : Type(c.Type), m_Key(c.m_Key), Callback(c.Callback), m_ID(c.m_ID) {}

    int m_ID;
    std::function<void()> Callback;
    EventType Type;
    SDL_Scancode m_Key;

private:

    friend bool operator==(const EventContainer& lhs, const EventContainer& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.m_ID == rhs.m_ID;
    }

};

std::vector<EventContainer> eventCallbacks; // Vector to store all event callbacks.
```

So far so good, then I have created a method to bind a particular event.

```
void BindMethod(std::function<void()>&& callback, // other params for struct)
{ 
     EventContainer cb;
     cb.Callback = callback;
     // other params

     eventCallbacks.push_back(std::move(cb));
}
```

In a main loop, what I do is checking the eventCallbacks vector, according to it's other parameters, and if the conditions I need are true, then I fire off the respective Callback. So far, I have no problems with this. Now comes my couple of concerns and questions.

There are 3 ways, as far as I can test, that I can call this BindMethod, to register a callback. I am wondering, in what manners do they differ? Especially memory wise, and I also of course would like to learn why.

First method:

```
  input->BindMethod(&TestMethod1); // I have a simple method, returning void, with no params called TestMethod1
```

Works wonderful, however I can't pass any params. Of course there is always an option of creating templates and supporting multi arguments, but I do not want to over-complicate things in the means of modularity or being "generic". I just need to get what I need.

So there comes the second option...

```
auto f = std::bind(TestMethod2, 5, 2); // 5,2 are my params for TestMethod2.
input->BindMethod(f);
```

This one works wonderfull as well, however I did not created many test cases for that, only basic ones, so I can't say for sure. Plus from what I have researched, community does not like std::bind that much.

And there goes the magic lambda, the third way

```
auto f2 = [testInteger] { TestMethod3(testInteger); };
input->BindMethod(f2);
```

The lambda way of doing things work pretty cool as well, however I suspect that in this case the question comes to my mind: What if the object instance that holds the member function inside the lambda body dies before the event is ever triggered and callback is called, and worse what if the callback would be called after object has died? So we have to implement some kind of a mechanism, that will take the corresponding callback struct out of the vector array right? However, as far as I have seen, it is kinda problematic to remove a struct from the vector array. First, I have given some IDs for the struct objects, then I tried to do these inside a particular unbinding method:

```
void Unbind(int pid)
{
EventCallbacks.erase(std::remove_if(EventCallbacks.begin(), EventCallbacks.end(), [&](EventContainer const & holder) {return holder.id == h.GetID(); }), EventCallbacks.end());
}
```

However, my program crashed. I checked the pid, which is passed correctly, and i checked that the holder.id is correct and it matches the pid, but somehow the program crashes, high likely something to do with the iterator, and couldn't find why.

So to sum things up:

1. The crucial differences between those 3 methods to call BindMethod method. And if there are any more variations that can be used, or any ideas, thoughts?
2. Is this a good way of organazing event callback handling? I have a struct, with the callback method and all the other data i need to parse, and a vector of those structs to call the methods when necessary.
3. I definitely need a solid, and concrete way of finding and deleting an element of the vector, without crashing, also need to understand why the crash occurs. Edit: A little more research, high likely because of the shifting the vector causes after removal. However, as far as I have found lists doesnt cause shifting, there is a more linear insertion and deletion approach over there. So, would it be better to switch to lists instead of vectors? Since I won't need to have a random access of any element inside my collection, all I will be doing is iterating it over a constant frame rate.
4. What about the dangers in the means of memory allocation while using std::function ? Is it a safe thing to base my architecture upon, or should I go with a better way?
5. Is there any steps I need to take, upon the removal of the struct objects from the vector, in the means of deallocating memory? Is there anything i need to be careful about?
6. I really do not feel really comfortable while using std::vectors, or basically std anything. Are there other cheap, functional approaches?

Thanks in advance, and apologize in advance for any misconceptions and terms I might have used, or any lack of delivering correct information.

Comment: *I definitely need a solid, and concrete way of finding and deleting an element of the vector, without crashing, also need to understand why the crash occurs.*  -- Not without seeing what `EventContainer` consists of, and I know it isn't just one member variable.  The `std::vector` will be making copies, and if your class does not have proper copy semantics, then expect bad things to happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh right, it's my bad. There isn't much actually, I thought I might need some more enumerations in it in the future for matching with other control structures. However, I have edited and written the whole struct as it currently is, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `EventCallbacks.` -- This needs to be a valid object also.  The gist of this is that there is nothing wrong with `std::vector`, `remove_if` or `erase`, so there is nothing to "fix" in that line you posted.  The only thing that can go wrong is 1) the vector is not valid (i.e. the EventsCallbacks is invalid instance), or 2) you specified incorrect arguments to `erase` and/or `remove_if` or 3) the type you're storing in `vector` has buggy copy semantics.  Otherwise `erase-remove_if` is guaranteed to work correctly.

Comment: Then I will make sure of the validity of it around the possible cases, thank you!